# WCF - working with WebReferences

Tags: wcf

What is the difference between adding a WCF Service WebReference and generating a proxy using svcutil.exe in a WCF Client program?

One thing I understand is, WebReference should not work in case of TCP, etc.

Any other distinction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the WCF Add Service Reference in Visual Studio is just a wrapper around calling svcutil. So the only difference is that the dialog may not expose all options svcutil exposes. Not be be confused with Add Web Reference in Visual Studio. This option adds the ASMX style reference  and does not use WCF or svcutil at all.